# Adding onclick event to input field programmatically in javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I want my `Input` field to look like this:

`<input type="submit" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)">`

But it's not working. I've tried to:

`Input.onclick = function () { deleteRow(this); };`

Doesn't work as well. My deleteRow function looks like:

```
    function deleteRow(o) {
        var p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried `Input.onclick = function (event) { deleteRow(event.target); };`? (I must say that I don't like to use the keyword `this` as  it's hard to know which object is it referencing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `id` to your `input` field and attach the `onclick` event to it:

```js
function DeleteRow(o) {
  var p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
  p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
}
document.getElementById("myinput").onclick = function () {
  DeleteRow(this);
};
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="myinput" value="Remove" onclick="DeleteRow(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. If you have no purpose of submitting, change `type=submit` to `type=button`

```js
function DeleteRow(o) {
  var p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
  console.log(p);
  p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    Goint to be deleted
    <form id="three">
      <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="DeleteRow(this)">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

but if you need to keep `type=submit`, i think you should pass event parameter as well like this

```
<!-- in case you need to use submit, pass event as parameter-->
<input type="submit" value="Remove" onclick="DeleteRow(this, event)">
```